# how to regex path in prometheus relabel_configs

Tags: prometheus, victoriametrics

i have a metric and label like this: namedprocess_namegroup_num_procs{groupname:"/data/home/user01/app.service.1/service"}, i want to get the last field: service, and the number in last but one field. i try to write a regex, but it is not work, someone know how to write it?

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [groupname]
    target_label: service
    regex: '"/data/home/user01/(.+)/(.+)'
    replacement: '${2}'
  - source_labels: [groupname]
    target_label: tmp
    regex: '[^/]+\d'
    replacement: '${1}'
  - source_labels: [tmp]
    target_label: num
    regex: '(\d)'
    replacement: '${1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

the question is fix, when scrape has happened and then want to change the label, must be use metric_relabel_configs, refer to https://www.robustperception.io/relabel_configs-vs-metric_relabel_configs/

```
metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [hostname]
    target_label: instance
    regex: ([^:]+)(:[0-9]+)?
    replacement: ${1}
  - source_labels: [groupname]
    target_label: service
    regex: /data/home/user01/(.+)/(.+)
    replacement: ${2}
  - source_labels: [groupname]
    target_label: num
    regex: /data/home/user01/(.+)\.([0-9]+)/(.+)
    replacement: ${2}
```